# TLS handshake of clients

Tags: ssl, browser, handshake

I'm working on an academic project about TLS handshakes and i have captured some TLS traffic generated by multiple clients (google chrome, firefox...) and I want to see if for a given browser the client hello message will always be the same or no (I have removed the GREASE extensions because they are added in a random way to the client hello message and I omitted the SNI). I found that the same browser generate multiple client hello messages. 
Is it normal to see such behavior or I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: Have you found an answer to your question?

Answer (score 0):

A TLS handshake is done for each TCP connection involved in HTTPS and it is common that the browser uses multiple TCP connections in parallel. This is probably what you see. Multiple TLS handshakes within the same TCP connection are uncommon but might happen if a server requires a client certificate only for a specific path and thus triggers a renegotiation.

Comment: Or if the session expires or if either peer wants to re-key the session.

Comment: @user207421: I don't think that any of these actually occur in practice and that's why I did not mention these.

Comment: No I'm just focusing on TLS layer parameters. For exemple why google chrome sends differents cipher suite ?